# Continuous function on Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

I'm wondering about how to solve this one:

Let $X$ be a topological Hausdorff space and $A$ a subspace of $X$.

Let $f:X \rightarrow A$ continuous such that $f(a) = a \hspace{5mm} \forall a \in A$.

Show that $A$ is closed.

Any ideas? I think I might get the solution just by adding compactness to hypoteses..

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Consider the map $g := (f, \operatorname{id}) : X \to X \times X$.  If $\Delta_X$ is the diagonal in $X \times X$ (which is closed by the hypothesis that $X$ is Hausdorff) then what can you say about $g^{-1}(\Delta_X)$?

Comment: $g^{-1}(\Delta _{X})$ is closed because g is continuous.. but could you explain me a little better? What do you mean by $(f,id)$?

Comment: Also why diagonal is closed? And how it is defined?

Comment: Another way of saying the definition of $g$ would be: $g(x) = (f(x), x)$.

Comment: @JamesArten Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space)

Comment: The diagonal is $\{ (x,y) \in X \times X \mid x = y \}$.  If $X$ is Hausdorff, and $(x, y) \in (\Delta_X)^c$, that means that $x \ne y$, so then choosing disjoint open neighborhoods $U,V$ of $x,y$, then we will have $(x, y) \in U \times V$ and $U \times V \subseteq (\Delta_X)^c$.

Comment: OK, so now try to find some relation between $A$ and $g^{-1}(\Delta_X) = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) = x \}$.